# "Simon Says" computer random choice not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am coding a "Simon Says" project for FreecodeCamp that keeps track of the computer's random color choices and the user click responses to follow the patterns of the colors that light up.

However, I am running into a problem . . . my colors don't change their opacity back to non-transparent when computer randomly runs choices.

I tried changing `setTimeout` to faster and slower time (e.g., 10 or 1000 milliseconds) to reset color back to non-transparent, but that has not worked.

This is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var colors = [".red",".blue",".yellow",".green"];
var classVariable = [];

$(".grass").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass(".grass").css("opacity",0.23);
  if($(this).is('.red')){
 var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
                myAudio.play();  
  }else if($(this).is('.blue')){
 var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3');
                myAudio.play();  
  }else if($(this).is('.yellow')){
  var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3');
                myAudio.play(); 
  }else if($(this).is('.green')){
  var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3');
                myAudio.play(); 
  }
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(".grass").css("opacity", 1);
}, 100);
});

function computerDisplay(){
for(var i = 0;i< colors.length;i++){
 let ranSelect = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 /*colors.length*/)];console.log(ranSelect);
    classVariable.push(ranSelect);console.log(classVariable);
 $(ranSelect).toggleClass(".grass").css("opacity",0.23);
 if($(ranSelect).is('.red')){
    setTimeout(function(){
var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
                myAudio.play();
      },1000);
 }else if($(ranSelect).is('.blue')){
    setTimeout(function(){
 var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3');
                myAudio.play(); 
      },1000);
  }else if($(ranSelect).is('.yellow')){
    setTimeout(function(){
  var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3');
                myAudio.play();
      },1000);
  }else if($(ranSelect).is('.green')){
    setTimeout(function(){
  var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3');
                myAudio.play(); 
        },1000);
  }
 var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
                myAudio.play();
setTimeout(function(){
    $(ranSelect).css("opacity", 1);
},500);
}
}


$(".start").click(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
 computerDisplay();
},1000);
});

});
```

```css
div{
  margin:0 auto;
}

.red{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
}


.blue{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.green{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:green;
}

.yellow{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fsp.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="fsp.js"></script>
  <body>
  <div class="container text-center">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="red col-xs-6 grass"></div>
  <div class="blue col-xs-6 grass"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="green col-xs-6 grass"></div>
  <div class="yellow col-xs-6 grass"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="start">
  <button>start</button>
  </div>
  </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the issue? When I click "start" it appears to randomly select a square, play a sound, and the square is briefly transparent then back to opaque. Could you explain the expected behavior and where it diverges?

Comment: i am having a problem with  more than on sound file playing when random square's are chosen by computer. The colors don't light up one at a time.  Instead three colors or two colors are lighting up at once. Thank you for replying.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate that behavior. I never see more than one square light up, I expect because `classVariable` is only ever appended to - never iterated. Is the code in the question up to date? If you want to iterate `classVariable` and light them up one at a time, you would have to handle each subsequent index after a timeout.

Comment: Sorry i missed that i posted the wrong version of my code here is the latest version. It does not run colors one by one as a normal click would  and sounds are all mixed up.  https://codepen.io/Ajax-2031/pen/gGGqpx?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had been iterating through the colors, and for each one selecting a random color and triggering it, so 1-4 [different] randomly selected would be triggered at once. Instead, I think each time `start` is clicked you would push a random color onto `classVariable` and then iterate those. You can't just iterate them with a `for` loop, though, because you want a delay between each. So you use a function that subsequently `setTimeout`s itself for the next iteration.

Give this JavaScript a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ['.red','.blue','.yellow','.green'];
  var classVariable = [];

  $(".grass").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass(".grass").css("opacity",0.23);
    if($(this).is('.red'))
    {
      var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
      myAudio.play();  
    }
    else if($(this).is('.blue'))
    {
      var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3');
      myAudio.play();  
    }
    else if($(this).is('.yellow'))
    {
      var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3');
      myAudio.play(); 
    }
    else if($(this).is('.green'))
    {
      var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3');
      myAudio.play(); 
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".grass").css("opacity", 1);
    },100);
  });

  function doTheThing(index)
  {
    if(index < classVariable.length)
    {
      var target = $(classVariable[index]);
      var myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');

      if(target.is('.red'))
      {
        myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3');
      }
      else if(target.is('.blue'))
      {
        myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3');
      }
      else if(target.is('.yellow'))
      {
        myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3');
      }
      else if(target.is('.green'))
      {
        myAudio = new Audio('https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3');
      }

      target.toggleClass(".grass").css("opacity",0.23);
      setTimeout(function(){
        myAudio.play();
      },250);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(target).css("opacity",1);
        doTheThing(index + 1);
      },500);
    }
  }

  function computerDisplay()
  {
    classVariable.push(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    console.log(classVariable);

    doTheThing(0);
  }


  $(".start").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      computerDisplay();
    },1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank You this issue was causing me great stress. I did not figure that a for loop does not delay between colors lighting up.

Comment: @AJAX101 Sure. In pretty much any other environment, you would be able to do like a `sleep` inside the `for` loop body to delay. To my knowledge JavaScript doesn't support that option and instead you have to use a continuation style with `setTimeout`: "this is the rest of the computation, to be executed X time in the future".

Comment: @AJAX101 Also, if this resolved the issue, could you accept the answer?

Comment: Thanks yes it was resolved for sound repeating. But i only have two new issues namely when a class color for example blue gets repeated twice or more. The color does not lit on and off as when only randomly chosen once by computerDisplay function. I would also like to keep track of the clicks that are made by user by clicking a color. I tried and codepen.io could not show it in the console due to it being to long description. Here is my current code. https://codepen.io/Ajax-2031/pen/dVmKOL?editors=1111 Thank you for your help